# How to get the element by Id from GWT DockLayoutPanel?

Tags: java, gwt, layout, web, docklayoutpanel

I am new to GWT and Java.

I tried create a DockLayoutPanel by GWT and the UI element from it.

But it failed and I got the Error message:

> [ERROR] [MainPage] - Unable to load module entry point class com.Test.MainPage (see associated exception for details)

java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.detachOnWindowClose(RootPanel.java:138)

some contents from MyDockLayoutPanel.ui.xml

```
 <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
   <g:north size='5'>
     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
       <g:Label>This is the NORTH panel</g:Label>
     </g:FlowPanel>
   </g:north>
   <g:west size='15'>
     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
       <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
     </g:FlowPanel>
   </g:west>
   <g:center>
     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.centerPanel}">
       <g:Label>This is the CENTER panel</g:Label>
       <g:HTML>
        <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>

        <table align="center">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter your name:</td>        
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
            <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </g:HTML>
     </g:FlowPanel>
   </g:center>         
 </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Some contents from MainPage.java

```
public void onModuleLoad() {


    SGCDockLayoutPanel p = new SGCDockLayoutPanel();
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(p);       

    final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
    nameField.setText("GWT User");
    final Label errorLabel = new Label();

    // We can add style names to widgets
    sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");

    // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
     Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element
    RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
    RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
    RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the full stacktrace ? You only posted starting 2 lines

Comment: can you post `modulename.gwt.xml` file?

Comment: Bhumika Thaker: I cant find modulename.gwt.xml in my project.
sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ: added full stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `HTMLPanel` and its own specific [`add`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html#add(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20java.lang.String)) instead of an `HTML` widget and trying to  make `RootPanel` work (you should see assertion failures the way you did it, which is why it fails)